# sigtimedwait() returns EAGAIN before timeout

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm trying to learn how to use sigtimedwait(), but I find that it's not waiting for the timeout to complete.  Below it seems to return EAGAIN 4s faster than it should (1s faster per 1min of timeout):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
    openlog ("SIG_TIMED_WAITER", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
    syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Started");

    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);

    struct timespec to;
    to.tv_sec = 240;
    to.tv_nsec = 0;

    int ret = sigtimedwait(&set, NULL, &to);
    if(ret < 0) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN) {
            syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "EAGAIN: TimedWait complete...");
        } else {
            syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "ERROR!");
        }
    }   else {
        syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Interrupted by signum: %d.", ret);
    }

    syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Terminated.");
    closelog();
}
```

And here's the output:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog|grep "SIG_TIMED_WAITER"
Jan  7 15:39:41 localhost SIG_TIMED_WAITER[13275]: Started
Jan  7 15:43:36 localhost SIG_TIMED_WAITER[13275]: EAGAIN: TimedWait complete...
Jan  7 15:43:36 localhost SIG_TIMED_WAITER[13275]: Terminated.
```

I had expected to see "EAGAIN: TimedWait complete..." logged four seconds later.

Is there something wrong with my code, or is this due to some other reason?  Note that I do not see this with, for example, a select() that waits for four minutes.

Comment: Interesting.  What does a `select(NULL, NULL, NULL, &to)` do on your system?  4s fast or not?

Comment: What is your platform? Could be that timer settings are wrong (in case of embedded platform I mean..)?

Comment: @LPs Its an ARM board (Olimex a20 to be precise). How could I check those settings?

Comment: I'll let you know in a minute @pilcrow

Comment: Did you compile your own kernel?

Comment: No I didn't, but I'm not using the mainline kernel. I'm using a [sunxi 3.4 kernel](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/linux-sunxi), as the mainline kernel is still incomplete in its support for some hardware for the SOC.

Comment: @pilcrow The select is working fine! Only sigtimedwait() is having this problem.

Comment: There's perhaps a difference in the on board timers, sigtimedwait() uses CLOCK_MONOTONIC , whilst the time used by select() and logged by syslog() would use CLOCK:_REALTIME which could be mapped to different hardware timers or a sofware emulated timer - so one of the timers isn't running correctly  - you could try to time this from a second source to figure out if sigtimedwait() actually waited for 240 seconds, or 236 seconds to figure out which of the timers is running too fast/too slow. I don't know what to do about it though. (Also make sure you're not running ntpd that could jump the clock

Comment: I too did suspect `ntpd` was causing this issue initially. I stopped it but the problem persists. I will try timing the program to see if I can get something.

Answer (score 1):

the `LOG_LOCAL1` is a reserved item,. I.E. do not use it

Instead use `LOG_USER`

It is easier to follow the action if the options parameter also has `LOG_PERROR`

Then the output will also be logged on `stderr`.

Here is a corrected/working version of the program.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <signal.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main( void )
{
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_NOTICE));
    openlog ("SIG_TIMED_WAITER", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PERROR | LOG_PID, LOG_USER);
    syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Started");

    sigset_t set;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);

    struct timespec to;
    to.tv_sec = 240;
    to.tv_nsec = 0;

    int ret = sigtimedwait(&set, NULL, &to);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN)
        {
            syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "EAGAIN: TimedWait complete...");
        }

        else
        {
            syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "ERROR!");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Interrupted by signum: %d.", ret);
    }

    syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Terminated.");
    closelog();

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04

(in this case, the `15212` is the PID of the console /terminal where the program was run.)

from the console/terminal (from the stderr output)

```
SIG_TIMED_WAITER[15212]: Started
SIG_TIMED_WAITER[15212]: EAGAIN: TimedWait complete...
SIG_TIMED_WAITER[15212]: Terminated.
```

from /var/log/syslog:

```
Jan  7 05:50:07 rkwill-desktop SIG_TIMED_WAITER[15212]: Started
Jan  7 05:54:07 rkwill-desktop SIG_TIMED_WAITER[15212]: EAGAIN: TimedWait complete...
Jan  7 05:54:07 rkwill-desktop SIG_TIMED_WAITER[15212]: Terminated.
```

Notice: The time between the initial output and the `EAGAIN` output was 4 minutes (240 seconds)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. It does indeed have something to do with the hardware I'm using. I too tried this on a PC (UBUNTU) and it's working fine.