# Catching SIGUSR1 with sigtimedwait()

Tags: linux, signals

I'm not new to programming, but pretty new to Linux. I'm trying to use signals to asynchronously catch a push on a button, like this:

1. Run a worker thread which raises SIGUSR1 when the button is pushed.
2. Run a loop (main thread) around sigtimedwait() that will rotate info every two seconds (as long as the button is not pushed) or break (when the button is pushed).

According to the [notes on sigtimedwait()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigtimedwait), one should block the signals you want to wait for, then call sigtimedwait(). But I never see sigtimedwait() catching the blocked signals. I have run the code below in a few ways to see what happens with different scenarios:

- Call to pthread_sigmask() disabled, call to signal() disabled,
  result: programs exits with message "User defined signal 1".
- Call to pthread_sigmask() disabled, call to signal() enabled, result:
  message "Button 1 pressed sync1 hit" appears, sigtimedwait() always
  returns EAGAIN.
- Call to pthread_sigmask() enabled, call to signal() disabled, result:
  message "Button 1 pressed" appears, sigtimedwait() always returns
  EAGAIN.
- Call to pthread_sigmask() enabled, call to signal() enabled, result
  of course same as previous because the handler will not be called.

All as expected, except for the fact that sigtimedwait() doesn't seem to catch the signal when it's pending.

I've looked into similar code, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655737/sigtimedwait-returns-eagain-before-timeout). But I don't understand how that particular code could work: SIGUSR1 isn't blocked, so raising that should immediately terminate the program (the default action for SIGUSR1).

It looks like I'm missing something here. What am I doing wrong? Or is the whole idea of using raise() in a worker thread wrong? I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Stretch (Debian 9.1), could there be a problem in that?

[I know printf() shouldn't be used in a signal handler, but for this purpose it works]

Any help appreciated, thx!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define PIN_BUTTON1 RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_22   // GPIO #24

// Thread function
void* check_button1(void* param)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (bcm2835_gpio_lev(PIN_BUTTON1) == HIGH)
        {
        printf("Button 1 pressed ");
        raise(SIGUSR1);
        }
        delay(250);
    }
}

// Signal handler, if applied
volatile sig_atomic_t usr_interrupt = 0;
void sync1(int sig)
{
    printf("sync1 hit ... ");
    usr_interrupt = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (!bcm2835_init())
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize BCM2835 GPIO library.");
        return 1;
    }
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(PIN_BUTTON1, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);

    sigset_t sigusr;
    sigemptyset(&sigusr);
    sigaddset(&sigusr, SIGUSR1);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigusr, NULL);
    signal(SIGUSR1, sync1);

    // Start the threads to read the button pin state
    pthread_t th1;
    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, check_button1, NULL);

    // Create a two second loop
    struct timespec timeout = { 0 };
    timeout.tv_sec = 2;
    usr_interrupt = 0;
    int nLoopCount = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Loop %d, waiting %d seconds ... ", ++nLoopCount, timeout.tv_sec);
        int nResult = sigtimedwait(&sigusr, NULL, &timeout);
        if (nResult < 0)
        {
        switch (errno)
        {
            case EAGAIN:    printf("EAGAIN ");   break;   // Time out, no signal raised, next loop
            case EINTR: printf("EINTR ");    break;   // Interrupted by a signal other than SIGCHLD.
            case EINVAL:    printf("EINVAL ");   exit(1); // Invalid timeout
            default:    printf("Result=%d Error=%d ", nResult, errno);   break;
        }
        printf("\n");
        continue;
        }
        printf("Signal %d caught\n", nResult);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**ADDENDUM:** In the meantime, I got this working by replacing *raise(SIGUSR1)* by *kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1)*. Strange, because [according to the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/raise) *raise(x)* is equivalent to *kill(getpid, x)* in single-threaded programs and to *pthread_kill(pthread_self(), x)* in multi-threaded ones. Replacing *raise(SIGUSR1)* by *pthread_kill(pthread_self, SIGUSR1)* has no effect. If anyone could explain this to me ...

Comment: Calling `raise(SIGUSR1)`  or `pthread_kill(pthread_self(), SIGUSR1)` in th1 is only going to send the signal to th1. The `sigtimedwait` you call in the main thread won't see it.

Comment: Thx, I re-read the manual and I think I was mixing up thread- and process-id's. So now I know it's logical that raise() and pthread_kill() don't work in this case and kill() does.